# Create list with geometric step size and print values corresponding to list elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sequence

This is my code:

```
c = [0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001]
for x in c:
   dydx[19]=(y[19+1]-y[19])/x
   error[19]= cos(19)-dydx[19]
   print(error[19])
```

I have 2 questions:

- How do you make the print function print out values corresponding to each element of the list like for `x = 0.1` error = ..?
- Is there a more efficient way of making a list with `(0.1,0.01.....10^-12)` and then using those x-values for the equation in the loop?

Comment: `numpy.logspace` constructs an array in log scale

Comment: thanks. does it work the same way as linspace?

Comment: Yes, except one is logarithmic and another is linear

Comment: Not sure I am following your first question, _How to print values corresponding to each element of the list..._. In your example, you have some code that creates the corresponding value in your `error` list at a specific index. Are you looking for a map between `c` and `error` so you easily print any item in `error` based on the value of an item in `c`?

Comment: I think that's what I mean, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list for a specific range of values incremented / decremented by a geometric step using a list comprehension with `range()`. Then, you could just create a dictionary for your errors and use your range list values as keys in the dictionary (you could also use list index values as keys if you were dealing with a list that might include duplicate values).

For example:

```
data = [10 ** x for x in range(-1, -13, -1)]

errors = {}
for x in data:
   # replace line below with your error value code
   errors[x] = f'error value for {x}'

print(errors[0.0001])
# OUTPUT
# error value for 0.0001
```